Scheduled Summary notifications in iOS often won't open
The notifications are set to display as Stacks. The scheduled summary stack appears normally, but no amount of tapping, holding or dragging can separate the stack into individual notifications for viewing and actioning. The only actions possible are to dismiss the whole group or wait for it to disappear automatically.
This has been happening on my personal iPhone SE 2020 ever since scheduled summaries were introduced with iOS 15.
I feel this happens about 70% of the time on my devices.
Is this problem user-fixable or simply a bug that needs to be reported to Apple?
